# How can I check if a specific fields of objects within an array or list are unique?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I have a list of objects like this,

```
person = [
    a = {
        name = john
        address = bakerfield
        phone = 1234
    },
    b = {
        name = stacy
        address = cloverfield
        phone = 4567
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I want to return true if all object's name and address fields are unique. It should return true if an object has same name but different address or vice versa.

I am fairly new to Java so having hard time figuring this one out. I tried implementing this with `contains` method but that didn't work.

Edit: fixed json formatting to object

**Edit 2: I was able to solve this problem using `Comparator.comparing` along with `TreeSet<>`.**

Comment: Is that supposed to be json? Because it's using weirdly inconsistent colons/equals ...

Comment: yeah, that's json. Sorry for the format. I have fixed it.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of JSON in a big string, or do you have objects that you just described using a JSON-like format? If the former, what code _do_ you have? How are you even reading this JSON in? Your question lacks quite a few details.

Comment: You can assume it's in objects format instead of json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add object with unique field to Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164179/how-to-add-object-with-unique-field-to-set)

Comment: @Joe My question has been solved. I have added an edit. Basically I just had to use TreeSet with Comparator.comparing

Comment: You can create an answer for your own question and actually mark it as solved, instead of leaving it open. However, this question has nothing to do with Spring or Spring Boot. And also, even though it might work, your solution doesn't sound like the best / most conventional way of solving this problem. Although I could be wrong, but then I think your question might not be worded the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to write a proper `equals` (and `hashCode` also! Read the first link below) method in your `Person` class that will compare all fields to understand whether the instance is duplicate or not.

When you will do this you can use a feature of java `Set` collection that guarantees that you will have only one instance of the object inside (the duplicate will be "ignored" when added) and compare the size of your initial array/list and the set created on this array/list

```
List<Person> people = someDeserializeJsonMethod();
return people.size() == new HashSet<>(people).size();
```

Read more:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: I already have deserializedJsonMethod set. I tried returning the value like you described but it still returned true even when whole object is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have a list. Do you mean you have: `List<Person> person;`?

Because you say you are trying to use `contains`. Contains compares objects, not values in objects.
For example if I had an ArrayList of strings.

```
ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>;
```

And I had some strings like:

```
String a = "red";
String b = "blue";
String c = "green";
String d = "green";
```

Then added a,b,c to the ArrayList, but left out d.

```
colors.add(a);
colors.add(b);
colors.add(c);
```

With the objects now in the arraylist. I can use compare like this:

```
colors.contains(a)
```

This will return true because the object 'a' is in the ArrayList. But if you try `colors.contains(d)` it'll return false. Even though the value of 'c' is 'green' which is the same value as 'd'. It isn't the same object. Because '.contains()' is just comparing objects and not the value of the object.

If you want to compare the values of a list/arrayList than you will have to a For loop.

```
public boolean comparePerson(ArrayList<Person> persons, Person person) {
//persons is your main list. And person is a single person that you want to see if they are in the ArrayList.

for (Person p: persons) {
    if (person.name == p.name) {
        if (person.address == p.address) {
        return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Optionally this is why having an Id field is useful. You'll only need to compare Ids and not multiple fields for a confident match.